# Как найти выход за пределы массива в С?

Tags: c

Имею зависший (логически, иначе вотчдог перезапустил бы) микроконтроллер. Прошивка написана на Си. Подключился отладчиком, поставил выполнение на паузу и смотрю состояние переменных в памяти. В большом количестве инициализированных, глобальных переменных (как правило контексты модулей) содержится какая-то белиберда. Прихожу к выводу что где-то обращаюсь к несуществующим элементам одного из буферов. Обнаружить методом тыка и сравнение адресов переменных не удалось, программа достаточно большая.

- Микроконтроллер: nRF52840
- IDE: Segger embedded studio

Вопросы:

1. Как обычно ищут такие ошибки?
2. Ситуация случается достаточно редко, можно ли как-то снять дам памяти для дальнейшего анализа? Точно знаю что можно с помощью nrfutil, но как с этим работать дальше - непонятно.
3. Может быть есть какие-то инструменты для визуализации памяти (переменных в ней), благо весь мой код без динамического выделения памяти.
4. Может быть есть какие-то инструменты, которые статическим анализом кода могут находить подобные ситуации.

Comment: Инструменты есть: статические анализаторы кода. Я бы начал именно с этого. В частности, в последнее время много рекламы одного такого анализатора с блюющим единорогом на логотипе. Можно попробовать бесплатно триалку.

Answer (score 2):

Есть хороший способ отладки встроенных систем. Создаете копию своей задачи в Visual Studio, и отлаживаетесь с комфортом. Внешние сигналы эмулируете данными из файла или прямо в отладчике. В Visual Studio доступны все инструменты и вся визуализация. Потом, когда задача отлажена, перетранслируете ее под свой целевой кристалл и запускаете. Логические ошибки типа обращения к чужой памяти таким способом ловятся очень просто. Что не ловится таким способом, так это ошибки реального времени. Также затруднительно применять такой способ если у Вас в Вашем целевом кристалле стоит какая-нибудь ОСРВ. Но даже в случае ОСРВ отдельные задачи можно отладить в Visual Studio. Это значительно облегчит последующую отладку на целевом кристалле.